# Codeigniter - Sagepay: 5006 Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, opayo

After I select pay with sagepay, select the card type, enter the card details and click on play not I get an `Internal Server Error 500: The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.` I am not sure, what is wrong. I am using the test card details from the sagepay website. If there is any part of code you would like to have a look with, kindly let me know. Thank you

Comment: did you find the solution ?, If yes kindly share the same.

Answer (score 2):

A 5006 error is usually because Sage Pay cannot connect to your NotificationURL.

Check that the url is externally visible, that your firewall isn't blocking it, that the notificationURL you supplied isn't throwing a 500 error, and that you haven't specified a port number as part of the URL (Sage Pay will only communicate on 80 / 443)...